# How to Get Image base64 using jQuery.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have save Image into database (datatype as Image). I need to retrieve the image using ajax.

I have convert byte[] into String like as follows.

```
if (dsrow["Photo"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    byte[] bytes = (byte[])dsrow["Photo"];
                    cObj._Photobyte = bytes;
                    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    cObj._Photo = "data:String/png;base64," + base64String;
                }
```

In my .aspx

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "employee.aspx/getemployeeByEmpNo",
            data: '{"no":"' + ui.item.value + '"}',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('[id$=lblName]').text(data.d.Name);
                $('[id$=imgphoto]').attr("ImageUrl", data.d.Photo);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });

 <asp:Image ID="imgphoto" runat="server"  width="100px"/>
```

It directly goes to error function. How to retrieve base64String ?

Comment: What's the error?  How is this actually failing?

Comment: Please show more of `employee.aspx`, especially `getemployeeByEmpNo`.